# MDX ignoring Excel filter

Tags: ssas, mdx, data-warehouse, olap

I'm just starting to get my head around MDX and I'm having trouble with a calculated member. I'm using the following MDX:

IIF(
ISEMPTY((Axis(1).Item(0).Item(0).Dimension.CurrentMember, [Measures].[Qty]))
,NULL
,([Product].[Product Code].CurrentMember.Parent, [Measures].[Qty])

)

What I'm trying to do is get a total quantity of the group of products displayed in a cube. I then use that total to divide by each product's quantity to get a "percent of total" measure. The above MDX does correctly return the total quantity of products displayed in any dimension. However, when a user in Excel changes the filter on which products are displayed, the MDX above still displays the total quantity for the whole group, ignoring which products the user has checked. I assume I'm lacking some basic understanding of MDX, how do I get the calculated measure to account for the product codes the user has selected in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio SQL Server Data Tools (if you are using that tool), you can browse to your cube, select the Calculations tab, and under Calculations Tools > Templates there is a template "Percentage of Total". The MDX this tool provides is flexible so that the percentage adjusts with the attributes of the hierarchy you've pulled into the pivot.

```
Case
// Test to avoid division by zero.
When IsEmpty
 ( 
    [Measures].[<<Target Measure>>] 
 ) 
Then Null

Else ( [<<Target Dimension>>].[<<Target Hierarchy>>].CurrentMember,
   [Measures].[<<Target Measure>>] ) 
 /
 ( 
   // The Root function returns the (All) value for the target dimension.
   Root     
   ( 
      [<<Target Dimension>>] 
    ), 
    [Measures].[<<Target Measure>>] 
 )
End
```

I found this option to work when developing to achieve what you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same member in MDX, that is already filtered in excel, otherwise you will cancel the excel filter. My solution was to create another column that looks the same. Now, when the user filters first three months, they are also filtered in the TOTAL (instead of including all 12).

```
SUM(
    TAIL(
        NONEMPTY(
            [dim_EntryDate].[Entry Year- Month Helper DO NOT USE].MEMBERS,
            [Measures].[Total Base Ex Charges]
        ),
        1
    ).ITEM(0)
 ,
    [Measures].[Total Base Ex Charges]
)
```

Comment: Please post the information as text, otherwise your answer may get deleted.